# downloading csv file from api

Tags: r, csv, https

I have an HTTPS API link which automatically downloads a CSV file. I wish to intercept this file directly through R by calling the link through some function.

Right now, I am using `download.file()` and `GET()` functions but they are either giving me authentication errors or gibberish data.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's 100% possible to use `httr:GET()` & other `httr` functions to solve your problem but we don't have a MWE to work from.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly what I use:

```
 urlcontent<- getURL(url)

 data<- read.table(textConnection(urlcontent), header=T, sep = ',')
```

Comment: Could you show us the errors? And the code you are using please?

Comment: also if the data is in html format use (urlcontent <- gsub('<tr />', '', urlcontent)) to make it legible for R